# Cumulative transformations in CSS

Tags: html, css, rotation

If I rotate a div having set the origin and then set the origin to something else and apply another rotation, only the second rotation is seen.
I understand that this is because that rotations are always done from the element's original position without transformations applied.

How would I perform a second rotation so that it is applied relative to the first rotation but with a new origin?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/yugDi)? Also, hello again.

Comment: Seems to be heading in the right direction, will try it out and see if it solved the problem

Comment: I'd like to try and avoid animations really.  Surely there is some way to get the transformation matrix already applied to an element and apply a second transformation to that matrix?

Comment: This is way out of my depth then... I'll spread it around to some people who might know.

Comment: If I was using the same origin it would be as simple as transform: function(a, b) function(a, b); but I'm not so it isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I finally found a way to achieve what I wanted.  You have to manually change the origin by translating and combine all transformations into one call to transform so that the translations and rotations create one transformation matrix and are therefore cumulative.

So for example if you want to rotate 30deg around 12,32 and then 20deg around 100,78 you would do:

```
#element{
    transform: translate(-12,-32) rotate(30deg) translate(12,32) translate(-100, -78) rotate(20deg) translate(100, 78);
}
```